# October CMS sessions are breaking?

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I've been trying to create a middleware in a plugin in October CMS, that takes from the input a value and stores it in session to be periodically displayed in a template.

Middleware function:

```
  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
  {
      session()->put('foo', input('foo'));
      logger('StartSession: foo: ', [session('foo')]);
      return $next($request);
  }
```

Registering middleware in plugin.php

```
    public function register()
    {
    $this->app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel')->prependMiddleware('October\Demo\Middleware\StartSession');
    }
```

Method in plugin for accessing session

```
    public function registerMarkupTags()
    {
       return [
           'functions' => [
               'session' => [Session::class, 'get']
            ]
       ];
    }
```

Usage in demo theme

```
<h1>{{ session('foo') }}</h1>
```

This works on the first run. If I put foo as query string foo is displayed on the page. However on a second run if I changed the query string to bar, foo persists on the page.

Here is an example of the issue in a fresh installed October Instance

https://github.com/reed-josh/october-session-issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm may be your middleware is executed before session is initialised not sure

> you can add your session data after all middleware executed

```
class StartSession
{
  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
  {
    $response = $next($request);

    // if we do not pass data hold old value 
    // do not override it with null
    if(input('foo')) {
        session()->put('foo', input('foo'));
    }

    logger('StartSession: foo: ', [session('foo')]);
    return $response;
  }
}
```

> Like this

**but make sure how session works you add session using get params it will not directly reflect it will reflect in your next request.**

Also I noticed that you did not add condition for input its better add it because other wise it will set `null` if no param is passed and your session data override unnecessarily.

if any doubt please comment.

Comment: Yes, this works as a work around. It does require me to check input first on page incase it's being changed and I need to display it on the same request, and then grab from session if the input is not set. I do think this is a bug, but I've filed a bug report. This is a decent work around so I'm gonna vote this as the answer, thank you.

Comment: I am not sure `its not a bug` otherwise session works just fine, i have also used sessions and it is just working fine. but thought `did not use in middleware` so i cant not be sure about not being it bug or so ...  :)